# How can I not rerun my code when an AppStorage var changes

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an appStorage var "isLoggedIn". On the start of my app, I monitor this variable and redirect the user depending on its value. When "isLoggedIn" is false, The user can go create an account navigating with navigationLinks. On the account creation, I change "isLoggedIn" to true. The purpose of this change is so that when the user closes and opens the app, I can direct them to their home screen immediately. The only problem is, "isLoggedIn" is acting like a @Binding var and triggering code at the start of my app. Is there a way for me to only reread the value once the user opens the app again?

This is the code where I redirect my user according to the AppStorage Variables

```
struct DispatcherView: View {

@AppStorage("isLoggedIn") var isLoggedIn = false
@AppStorage("lastLoggedEmail") var lastLoggedEmail = ""
@AppStorage("lastLoggedUserType") var lastLoggedUserType = ""
@AppStorage("lastLoggedUserPassword") var lastLoggedUserPassword = ""

@State var isActive: Bool = false
@State var waitTime: Bool = false

var body: some View {

VStack{
    
    if self.isActive{
        if isLoggedIn == false{

            StartUpView()
                .onAppear(perform: {

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                    }
                })
        }
        else{

        if lastLoggedUserType == "Driver"{

                DriverContentView(email: $lastLoggedEmail, userType: $lastLoggedUserType)
                    .onAppear(perform: {

                        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: lastLoggedEmail, password: lastLoggedUserPassword) { (res, err) in
                            if err != nil{print(err as Any)}
                        }

                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                        }
                    })

            }
            else if lastLoggedUserType == "Admin"{

                AdminContentView(email: $lastLoggedEmail, userType: $lastLoggedUserType)
                    .onAppear(perform: {

                        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: lastLoggedEmail, password: lastLoggedUserPassword) { (res, err) in
                            if err != nil{print("ERROR signing user back in\(String(describing: err))")}
                        }

                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (_,_) in

                        }
                    })

            }

        }
    }
    else{
        
        VStack{
            
            Spacer()
        Image("splashScreen")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .animation(waitTime == false ? .none : .spring())
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
    }
}
.onAppear(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
        withAnimation{
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        waitTime = true
    }
}
}
}
```

In the sign up view, once I have confirmed the users info, I make these changes.

```
                                    lastLoggedEmail = email
                                    lastLoggedUserPassword = password
                                    lastLoggedUserType = "Admin"
                                    isLoggedIn = true
```

Once these changes are made, I'm pretty confident that the app goes back to the DispatcherView and reruns the code according to the new changes. I came to this conclusion by putting dummy destinations in the navigationLink in the SignUpView. No matter what view I put in as a destination, it would briefly show that view and then pop to the dispatcher view where it responds to my changes.

I do not want the app to react to these changes immediately(In a similar fashion to @Binding and @State variables). I only want it to use them for the next time a user launches the app.

Comment: Don’t use the AppStorage property wrapper. Read and write to UserDefaults without it.

Comment: @jnpdx I have tried userDefaults, the same thing happens.

Comment: How I read userDefaults: if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userLoggedIn") == false {...}

Comment: How I write to userDefaults: UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "userLoggedIn")

Comment: Then there isn’t enough code here to diagnose the issue. You stated that the view was refreshing because of the change in the AppStorage property. UserDefaults alone won’t trigger a refresh. Please include a [mre] that can be debugged.

Comment: @jnpdx In the Sign Up view if I were to replace isLoggedIn = true to UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "userLoggedIn")  the error persists. However if I comment out UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "userLoggedIn" the app works as expected.

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).